# Parsing S-Expression in C# (KiCAD PCB file)

Tags: c#, kicad

I'm writing a *.NET API (C#)* to manage KiCAD PCB files. Their format *according to docs* ([here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~stambaughw/kicad/doc-read-only/download/head:/1115%4016bec504-3128-0410-b3e8-8e38c2123bca:trunk%252Fkicad-doc%252Fdoc%252Fhelp%252Ffile_formats%252Ffile_formats.pdf/file_formats.pdf)) is a sort of **S-Expression**. I tried reusing some **S-Expression** parsers but for several reasons they could not fit my needs so I decided to write one but I found myself stuck.
As a first try I wrote down a simple function that recursively descend into the the file structure and create a `System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode` hierarchy that match the structure (I used `TreeNode` because I use a `TreeView` component to depict the parsed structure):

```
    private TreeNode Parser(StreamReader srStream, TreeNode tnCurrentNode)
    {
        bool _string = false;

        do
        {
            TreeNode _tnNode = null;
            char _c;

            _c = (char)srStream.Read();

            if (_string)
            {
                tnCurrentNode.Text += _c;
                if (_c == '"')
                    _string = false;
            }
            else
                switch (_c)
                {
                    case '(':
                        _tnNode = new TreeNode();
                        tnCurrentNode.Nodes.Add(Parser(srStream, _tnNode));
                        break;

                    case ')':
                        return tnCurrentNode;
                    case '\n':
                    case '\r':
                        break;

                    case '"':
                        tnCurrentNode.Text += _c;
                        _string = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        tnCurrentNode.Text += _c;
                        break;
                }
        } while (!srStream.EndOfStream);

        return tnCurrentNode;
    }
```

After that I wrote down a serializer to write back files.
Everything works fine but there's a case that's improperly handled by my parser and to which I've not been able to find a proper solution:

```
(fp_text value V23105 (at -2 0 180) (layer F.SilkS) hide
  (effects (font (size 1 1) (thickness 0.25)))
)
```

The **hide** token position is not correctly managed (it cannot be *serialized*  in the original position). The reason is simple: while the parser correctly handles subnodes, since they starts with an opening bracket, it simply *ignores* values that are *at the same level* (i.e. values separated by white spaces) such as **hide** option. How can I manage such condition? I tried in several ways but I just got into a number of stack overflow exceptions (I just lost control of recursion).

In the meanwhile I defined a custom class to handle nodes (to be used instead of `TreeNode`):

```
public class KiCADNode
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public NodeType Type { get; set; }

    private readonly List<KiCADNode> _Nodes = new List<KiCADNode>();
    public ICollection<KiCADNode> Nodes { get { return _Nodes; } }

    public static implicit operator TreeNode(KiCADNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return null;

        TreeNode _treenode = new TreeNode();

        _treenode.Text = node.ToString();

        foreach (KiCADNode _node in node._Nodes)
            _treenode.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)_node);

        return _treenode;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (Type == NodeType.List)
            _sb.Append('(');

        _sb.Append(Value);

        if (Type == NodeType.Atom)
            _sb.Append(' ');

        if (Type == NodeType.List)
            _sb.Append(')');

        return _sb.ToString();
    }
    public KiCADNode()
    {
        Type = NodeType.Atom;
    }

    public KiCADNode(NodeType type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public KiCADNode(string value) : this()
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public KiCADNode(string value, NodeType type) : this(value)
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    private static KiCADNode Parse(StreamReader input)
    {
        KiCADNode _node = new KiCADNode("PCB");
        return Parser(input, _node);
    }

    private static KiCADNode Parser(StreamReader input, KiCADNode current_node)
    {
        bool _string = false;

        while (!input.EndOfStream)
        {
            KiCADNode _new_node = null;
            char _c;

            _c = (char)input.Read();

            if (_string)
            {
                current_node.Value += _c;
                if (_c == '"')
                    _string = false;
            }
            else
                switch (_c)
                {
                    case '(':
                        _new_node = new KiCADNode(NodeType.List);
                        current_node.Nodes.Add(Parser(input, _new_node));
                        break;

                    case ')':
                        return current_node;
                    case '\n':
                    case '\r':
                        break;

                    case '"':
                        current_node.Value += _c;
                        _string = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        current_node.Value += _c;
                        break;
                }
        } 

        return current_node;
    }

    public static KiCADNode Parse(string filename)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
            return null;

        using (StreamReader _input = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            return Parse(_input);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common parsing idiom. In EBNF

> node :: atom | "(" list ")"
>
> list ::= node | list node

which in C# one could implement as an abstract base class, and a class for node, atom and list. I did something similar here https://github.com/bobc/eakit/tree/master/source/kicad_tools/SExpression

Comment: Thanks I'll check your code ASAP. I see you're working on a similar problem ... you are trying to parse KiCAD board files?

Comment: Yes, generally to read/write KiCad schematic, board, symbol and footprints.